# Display a Jdialog box when a Jbutton recieves mouse click

Tags: java, user-interface

I am stuck on a problem where i click on a menu item and need it to bring up a JDialog Box but it wont bring it up. The coding i have researched and found that i should be using if im not mistaken is something like

```
if(evt.getSource == Jmenuitem1)
Jdialog.setVisible(true);
Jdialog.setBounds (400,0,400,400)
```

Below is the full coding for the class im working on. Why is it doing nothing when i click on the menu item.

```
package dvdlibrary2;

import javax.swing.JDialog;




public class UImain extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public UImain() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        input1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        iTitle1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        iGenre = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        iRating = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        iLength = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        iDescription = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        mlist = new javax.swing.JList();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dtitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        ddescription = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        dgenre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        drating = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        dlength = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        newdvd = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        input1.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(400, 0, 400, 400));
        input1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        input1.setVisible(false);
        input1.setBounds(400,0,400,400);

        iTitle1.setText("Title");

        iGenre.setText("Genre");

        iRating.setText("Rating");

        iLength.setText("Length");

        iDescription.setText("Description");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout input1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(input1.getContentPane());
        input1.getContentPane().setLayout(input1Layout);
        input1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(iDescription)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(iLength)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2))
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(iRating)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(iGenre)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(iTitle1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(159, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        input1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(iTitle1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(iGenre)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(iRating)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(iLength)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(input1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(iDescription)
                        .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(input1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );

        input1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(newdvd);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mlist.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(mlist);

        jLabel1.setText("Movies In Library");

        dtitle.setEditable(false);

        ddescription.setColumns(20);
        ddescription.setRows(5);
        ddescription.setEnabled(false);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(ddescription);

        dgenre.setEditable(false);

        drating.setEditable(false);

        dlength.setEditable(false);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        newdvd.setText("New DVD");
        newdvd.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                newdvdMouseClicked(evt);
                newdvdMouseClicked1(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(newdvd);

        jMenuItem2.setText("About");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Preferences");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(dtitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                                .addComponent(dgenre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(drating, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(dlength, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 47, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(dtitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(dgenre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(drating, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(dlength, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)))
                .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                        

    private void newdvdMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
       if(evt.getSource()== newdvd)
            input1.setVisible(true);
            input1.setBounds(400,0,400,400);

    }                                   

    private void newdvdMouseClicked1(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    


    public static void uimain() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UImain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JTextArea ddescription;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dgenre;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dlength;
    private javax.swing.JTextField drating;
    private javax.swing.JTextField dtitle;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iDescription;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iGenre;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iLength;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iRating;
    private javax.swing.JLabel iTitle1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog input1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JList mlist;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem newdvd;


}
```

Test Results

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package dvdlibrary2;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jon
 */
public class MainTest {

    public MainTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of main method, of class Main.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        System.out.println("main");
        String[] args = null;
        Main.main(args);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

}

Test of UImain class

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package dvdlibrary2;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jon
 */
public class UImainTest {

    public UImainTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of uimain method, of class UImain.
     */
    @Test
    public void testUimain() {
        System.out.println("uimain");
        UImain.uimain();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a test case instead of this full code?

Comment: how do i do that, sorry, i have never done that before

Comment: Nevermind, i figured out how, i edited the original post, test results are at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ActionListener instead of MouseListener to process events. Change:

```
newdvd.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        newdvdMouseClicked(evt);
        newdvdMouseClicked1(evt);
    }
});
```

to:

```
newdvd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input1.setVisible(true);
        input1.setBounds(400,0,400,400);
    }
});
```

And your dialog will show up.

Comment: Ok, so tell me why this worked with a actionperformed vs a mouse clicked.........

Comment: That's the way to handle events from the `MenuItem`. How it works is described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#event

I've never checked myself but I suppose that MouseEvent is consumed by the popup and that is the reason why menu items do not receive this event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mouseClicked` event use:

```
public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
```